# Extracting data from a multicolumn file with missing entries

Tags: python, perl, awk

I am trying to extract some data from a [multicolumn file](http://pastebin.com/DfYhBGcN) named *mass.mas03*. Columns are seperated by `tab`. When the data starts you can see that there are entries that are empty(i.e. line 44 VS line 45).

The whole idea is to extract data from a specific column(*MASS EXCESS*, that is) for a number of rows, take the sum and create a horizontal line on a xy-axes system, with the y cordinate being the sum of those values.

As an example take lines 41,65,74

```
  -1    0    1    1 H          7288.97050    0.00011      0.0      0.0   B-      *                1 007825.03207    0.00010
   0    4    4    8 Be         4941.672      0.035     7062.435    0.004 B- -17979.819    1.001   8 005305.103      0.037
   4    7    3   10 Li   -n   33050.581     15.124     4531.555    1.512 B-  20443.910   15.123  10 035481.259     16.236
```

I want to do: 7288.97050 + 4941.672 - 33050.581 = - 20819.9385 . If I use an `awk` command to have access on the data, I face this problem

```
> awk '/8 Be/ {print $6}' mass.mas03
  4941.672 
>awk '/10 Li/ {print $6}' mass.mas03
  -n
```

I don't know if `awk` is the best option to do not only the data selection, as well as the "plot" so I am open to suggestions!

An obvious solution would be to use `$7` instead of `$6` where needed, but it's a large file and I'm trying to automate a bit the whole process.

Is there a way to "chose" the desired data and apply some simple calclations on them, for this weird column file?

Comment: I suspect with `awk` you need to supply the `-F'\t'` option to set the field separator to tab, and then use `$7` instead.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 33050.581 (and not adding it)?

Comment: If columns are separated by tabs, you could just check if there are 1 or two consecutive tabs, to determine if a column is empty or not.. (as pointed out by @TLP)

Comment: @TLP: I used `awk -F'\t' '/10 Li/ {print $7}' mass.mas03` and `awk -F'\t' '/10 Li/ {print $6}' mass.mas03` but I get an empty output.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I have to do this substraction for theory reasons.

Comment: @Thanos Then perhaps you need to check which field the number you want is in, if it is not field number 7?

Comment: @TLP: I tried `awk -F'\t' '/Be/ {print FNR $0}' mass.mas03 ` and as expected I got all entries. I also tried `awk -F'\t' '/Be/ {print FNR  $1}' mass.mas03 ` and although I expected only the 1st column, I got all columns. If I move on(i.e. `$2, $3, $4, ... , $`) only the `FNR` is printed...

Comment: Try using `/10\tLi/` instead

Comment: @HåkonHægland: `awk '/10\tLi/ {print $0}' mass.mas03 ` produces empty output. I expected a whole line, that would include *10"tab"Li*. I am mistaken in that?

Comment: Then you should check if your file is really tab separated.. `/10\tLi` works for me.. (after I edited your sample such that each column is really tab separated, there where a lot spaces there at beginning)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: How can I check that? The actual file can be found here  http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/masses/mass.mas03

Comment: The file is not tab separated (it is only spaces between columns).. You need to postprocess it before sending it to awk

Comment: @What do you mean by *postprocess it before sending it to awk*? I tteid to make it "prettier" by using `awk '{print FNR "\t" $0}' mass.mas03` but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: See my answer below..

Answer (score 2):

To replace spaces with tabs, you can try the following:

```
awk -f f.awk mass.mas03 > mass.mas03.tab
```

where `f.awk` is:

```
/^1N-Z/ {
    f=1
    print
    getline
    print
    next
}
f {
    gsub(/ +/,"\t")
}
{print}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This postprocessing messes up a bit the file. If I type `awk '/He/ {print $7}' mass.mas03.tab` you can see that again there is the same problem, which is caused by the first column, I think. The ouptut is `0.00242    
0.00006    
11386.233  
0.755      
26101.038  
31598.044  
40939.429  
++         
           `

Comment: @Thanos Yes it does not work for empty fields. In that case it should have inserted two tabs instead of a single tab.. I am trying to figure out how to solve that..

Comment: @Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: If I import the `mass.mas03` on Excel and press *allign text left* it does the job. If after excel, I use `awk -F'\t' '/H/ {print $8}' mass.mas03` it seems that the right values are printed. The question now is how to make simple calculations on specific entries of the file?

Comment: @Thanos That is great.. What kind of calculations do you have in mind?

Comment: The idea is to give a set of element(s)(i.e. 1 H, 10 B), get the mass excess of each and sum them up. Then give another set of element(s)(i.e. 11 C), get the mass excess and substract it from the previous sum.

Comment: @Thanos Sorry I am not so familiar with chemistry. What do you mean by `1 H` and `10 B`? Ok I think I get it.. Its the numbers in column 5 and 6, right?

Comment: @Thanos How do you calculate the mass excess?

Comment: It doen't have to do with chemistry! If you look at the file there are 2 columns: `A` and `EL`. In every `A\tEL` combination, there is an `MASS EXCESS` value. And exactly, I am reffering to cols 5, 6 and 8 respectively!

Comment: So for the given `1 H` and `10 B` the mass excess is `7288.97050+12050.731`?

Comment: Do you plan to give these elements (`1 H`,`10 B`, `11 C`, ..) as input data to the `awk` program?

Comment: Exactly! For both of questions!!! In particular for the second one, this would be ideal!

Comment: @Thanos Then we imagine the following input file: Line 1: "1 H", Line 2: "10 B", Line 3: "11 C", and so on.. and the first two lines are to be added, the next line is to be subtracted, the next two are to be added, and so on?

Comment: Well, there could be a case where Line1-(Line2+Line3). My intention was-before making a gui-to do something like that: Number of first Set, Number of second set, Line 1: "1 H", Line 2: "10 B", Line 3: "11 C". The numbers of forst and second set will define which case is it: (Line1+Line2+...)-(Line3+) or Line1-(Line2+Line3+...) or whatever combination!

Comment: @Thanos Since we are departing a little bit from your original question, maybe we should continue discussion in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43670/discussion-between-hakon-haegland-and-thanos)

Answer (score 2):

if your data is really tab-separated then you'd simply use:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ whatever }'
```

If it's fixed width fields instead then you should use:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="list of field widths"} { whatever }'
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
  -1    0    1    1 H          7288.97050    0.00011
   0    4    4    8 Be         4941.672      0.035
   4    7    3   10 Li   -n   33050.581     15.124

$ gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 5 5 5 5 5 12 12"} {print $7}' file
  7288.970
  4941.672
 33050.581
```

Note that FIELDWIDTHS is gawk-specific. I've no idea if those are the correct field widths or not for your data, I just did a ballpark estimate to demonstrate the approach. Obviously if you want to convert it from fixed-with fields to tab-separated then it's trivial to do that:

```
$ gawk -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 5 5 5 5 5 12 12"} {$1=$1}1' file
  -1        0       1       1    H                7288.97050        0.00011
   0        4       4       8    Be               4941.672          0.035
   4        7       3      10    Li      -n      33050.581         15.124
```

and if you want to strip off the leading/trailing spaces from each field:

```
$ gawk -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 5 5 5 5 5 12 12"} {$1=$1; gsub(/ /,"")}1' file
-1      0       1       1       H               7288.97050      0.00011
0       4       4       8       Be              4941.672        0.035
4       7       3       10      Li      -n      33050.581       15.124
```

Comment: +1 `FIELDWIDTHS` seems to be a good idea for this kind of input, where spaces are used to separate columns..

Answer (score 1):

to me the file is still structured for Fields starts at one point and ends at another
a specific field always has the same number of charecters
so it is a fixed width fields

$7 starts at 35 and its width is 12

use awk '/Li/ {print substr($0,35,12)}' mass.mas03